# Facebook App Coding: Friend selector formular without FBML?

Tags: facebook, fbml, selector, friend

Hey guys,
as far as I know are FBML Codes not working anymore on Facebook unfortunately..

So does anybody< here has an idea on how to use the friend selector formular which could be used easily via FBML code in our facebook applications??

would be great if someone could help (not only me ;) ) out!

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out the [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) reference page. It looks like it may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the Invite Friends UI overlay? You're probably not going to find an FBML solution since Facebook are retiring it.  This is how to do it using the Javascript API:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', message: 'This is my message'});
```